# Spring integration test hanging, after having run successfully for a while

Tags: java, database, spring-data-jpa, h2

I inherited a Spring integration test, which has been running fine for months now, but since yesterday it has been hanging while setting up the "h2" database even before the "setup" method is run. After debugging, I found that, it's hanging at the driver level, when it tries to read some data during the step of running some "import" data scripts. The test config for the database is

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "x.y.z", entityManagerFactoryRef = "myEntityManagerFactory")
public class DatabaseConfig{

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @Primary
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName("XY").addScript("schema-xy.sql").build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public EntityManagerFactory fcEntityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
         HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "import-xy.sql");


        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("x.y.z");
        factory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }
```

}

The test is more or less like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { MyApplication.class, DatabaseConfig.class})
@WebIntegrationTest({ "server.port=12345", "management.port=12345", "security.user.name=testuser","security.user.password=testpassword" })
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ServerProperties serverProperties;

    private String contextPath;

    private String basePath;

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    //
}
```

There have been no apparent changes to this code. Could someone give some pointers on how to attack this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done an upgrade to some dependency?

Comment: No, there wasn't any dependency changes

Answer (score 0):

So this is very strange, but during my debugging I noticed that the test always hung on the first "Insert" statement, so I started playing with that, and I found some strange behavior where when I broke up the insert statements into separate lines, than the test started running fine :-S , which basically fixed my problem, but of course, I don't understand why. :-S